# Android post a JSON Object

Tags: android, json, http-post, androidhttpclient

I would like to post a json in my data base (RDF), My json is correct but i can't send it
this is my code:

I would like to post this json into my database help plz
////////

```
HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://www.hds.utc.fr/memorae/pr/api/swars/note");

         try {
             // JSON data:
            jsonA.put("index", "datjsonArray");//datjsonArray

                jsonA.put("sharingspace","datjsonArray1" );//datjsonArray1
                jsonA.put("content", "test");
                jsonA.put("title", "test");
                jsonA.put("aurhor", "amc2:userAPIConcept53a07a9a1758d");
                jsonA.put("distributor","datjsonArray2 ");//datjsonArray2
                jsonA.put("date", "dat");
                jsonA.put("type", "note"); 


             String json = jsonA.toString();



             StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);  
             se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
             Log.i("se", ""+se);
             httppost.setEntity(se);
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

             if(response!=null){
                 InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); 
             }

         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.i("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
         }
```

error

07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012): Erreur à tel endroit
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:116)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-05 02:10:06.410: E/NomDeMaClasse(2012):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You are getting an expcetion?

Comment: Please post the exception, if you're getting one.

Comment: i dont have any error or exception

Comment: i would like to create a json like this :                                {

  "type" : "note",

  "index" : [

    "Mandrin_Automatique",

    "Mandrin_Manuel"

  ],

  "distributor" : [

    "amc2:userAPIConcept5388541197bcc"

  ],

  "author" : "amc2:userAPIConcept5388541197bcc",

  "content" : "Test",

  "sharingspace" : [

    "ate:spaceAPIConcept539181b3a0d8d",

    "ate:spaceAPIConcept538888ab4848c"

  ],

  "date" : "04\/07\/2014",

  "title" : "test juillet"

} and send in my data base (url) you can help me plz

Comment: You are not getting error? Wel you are not reading the content your php script echos. You are only opening `InputStream in` but not reading from that stream. Add code which reads from the strem to get the echoed text. Display and log the text. It will contain error information.

Comment: Further you cannot say "i want to post this to my database". Better: You will post the json to a php script. Depending on your script the received data can be inserted in a database by that script.

Comment: i use the same script with Ios and i can post the json but with android i can't

Comment: Interesting info. But as reaction to my last comment irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Change tthe two lines

```
json1.put("index", "datjsonArray");//datjsonArray
jsonA.put("aurhor", "amc2:userAPIConcept53a07a9a1758d");
```

to

```
jsonA.put("index", "datjsonArray");//datjsonArray
jsonA.put("author", "amc2:userAPIConcept53a07a9a1758d");
```

You will not get error messages from php anymore. Only a lot of odbc syntax errors messages. Probable reason: `"datjsonArray"` should be `datjsonArray`.

But... to see the messages you have to grab the echos from the php script by reading them from `InputStream in`.

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly do you want to know? Dit you apply the suggested changes? Did it change things? Why aren't you reporting?

Comment: my wcript php work with ios ok but  i think that  the probleme with my  code android

Comment: Again your reaction is not to the point. Please answer all my questions and react on all my comments. Thats how it is supposed to go on a forum like this.

Comment: i do all change and i havent error in php but i can t cnnect to my triple store

Comment: and all this note are create with iphone

Comment: je constate que mon code n excute pas cette ligne // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: Ok. But then you will have error in the logcat. Change `Log.i("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");` to `Log.i("Error", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());`. Try again and post the logcat with errors and stacktrace here.

Comment: the mmessage is : Exception: null

Comment: Impossible. POST THE LOGCAT.

Comment: what mean ? what is the solution

Comment: Sigh... Is there a doktor in the house?

Comment: what is the sokution plz

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious exception

```
NetworkOnMainThreadExeption
```

Place your code in an AsyncTask or thread. AsyncTask is easiest.
You can find many examples on this site.

If you only had posted the logcat earlier...

Answer (score 0):

ihave this error:i have this error olso :07-05 23:10:06.290: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.300: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.300: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.300: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.340: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.410: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.460: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.460: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.500: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-05 23:10:06.530: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg